# Using Typeahead.js for dropdown list replacement MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I currently use MVC dropdown list for displaying my dropdown lists. I am looking to move my entire page to JS and web api's. The current code functions and works fine with my controller. I have some sample code that works for main table on this API but Looking to see if I can get it to function the same way I use the MVC dropdown plugins but with TypeAhead.js

Current Code for StanceType DropDownList:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Stances.Name) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Stances.Name, new { @class = "form-control col-lg" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Stances.StancesTypesId) @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Stances.StancesTypesId, new SelectList(Model.StancesTypes, "Id", "Name"), "Select Stance Type", new { @class = "form-control col-lg" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Stances.BrandsId) @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Stances.BrandsId, new SelectList(Model.Brands, "Id", "Name"), "Select Brand", new { @class = "form-control col-lg" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Current Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details() {
 var stancesTypes = _context.StancesTypes.ToList();
 var priority = _context.Priority.ToList();
 var brands = _context.Brands.ToList();
 var viewModel = new StancesViewModel {
  StancesTypes = stancesTypes,
   Priority = priority,
   Brands = brands
 };
 return View("Details", viewModel);
}
```

This is new typeAhead.js and API Controller that I am trying but it just displays the Name data from the Stances database and not the Name field for StanceTypes field.

```
var stances = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('StancesTypesId'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: '/api/stances?query=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

$('#stancetype').typeahead({
  minLength: 0,
  hightlight: true
}, {
  name: 'StancesTypesId',
  display: 'name',
  source: stances
});


// GET /api/Stances
public IEnumerable <StancesDto> GetStances() {

  //get accountid from user
  string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
  var userAccountID = _context.AccountProfile.Single(c => c.UserId == userId);

  var stancesTypes = _context.StancesTypes.ToList();
  var priority = _context.Priority.ToList();
  var brands = _context.Brands.ToList();

  var viewModel = new StancesViewModel {
    StancesTypes = stancesTypes,
      Priority = priority,
      Brands = brands
  };

  return _context.Stances.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map <Stances, StancesDto> ).Where(c => c.AccountGUID == userAccountID.AccountGUID);
}
```